# XSocket licensing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-rest, xsocket

I'm currently in a project using XSockets. Understand that the project is open source and free to use. But it still requires a valid license to run. Can I know where I can get this license?
The path given as information is invalid now. I have also mailed the developer group but to no avail.
Any help is appreciated.

Data thrown by XSocket during run:

```
2018-06-21 09:50:29 [Warning] No valid license key found in configuration file, starting in evaluation mode
2018-06-21 09:50:29 [Information] License Information: LicenseTerms { LicenseType: Evaluation, Payed: False, IsValid: True, ValidationAttempts: 0, AllowedControllers: 1, AllowedMethodsPerController: 10, OfflineLicense: False, Scaling: False, ConnectionLimit: 3, StartDate: 06/21/2018 09:50:29, EndDate: 06/21/2018 10:20:29, OwnerName: "Evaluation", Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 }
2018-06-21 09:50:29 [Warning] The XSockets.NET Evaluation license will only run for 30 minutes with a limit of 3 simultaneous connections
2018-06-21 09:50:29 [Information] Get a free developer license with all features enabled at http://xsockets.net
2018-06-21 09:50:29 [Warning] The XSockets.NET Evaluation license issued to "Evaluation" will expire 06/21/2018 10:20:29
2018-06-21 09:50:29 [Information] Server starting at 06/21/2018 09:50:29 with interceptors True
```

Comment: https://uffebjorklund.gitbooks.io/xsockets-net-5/content/the_basics/add_the_license.html You do need to obtain a license from the developers. If no response, then probably the project is dead.

Comment: Yeah that's the reason I wrote here, hoping to get someone from that group to acknowledge. Seems I better look for other solution. Thanks @LexLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, found another project which is of the same logic as XSocket at 
[websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#per-message-compression)

Hopefully it will help someone else like me.
Thanks.